# Keras - LSTM on embedding - dense layers

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to replicate the work of a paper (on binary classification of text) to form a benchmark for my model- the paper said: "these tokenized tweets are transformed into an embedding using the aforementioned pretrained GloVE model. The resulting sequence of vectors is then fed to the LSTM that outputs a single 32-dimension vector that is then fed forward through 2 ReLU activated layers of size 128 and 64 to yield the output"

So would that translate to :

```
model_glove1 = Sequential()
model_glove1.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, 25, input_length=50, weights=[embedding_matrix25],trainable=False))
model_glove1.add(LSTM(32))
model_glove1.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model_glove1.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model_glove1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',auc_roc])
```

The output of the last dense layer will be of shape (64,) when the loss function binary_crossentropy expects of shape(1,)

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: @giser_yugang This is the architecture of the model that is described in the paper - deep neural nets for bot detection (name of the paper) . I am trying to replicate it. But how can I pass a dense 64 layer output to a binary classifier problem ? which they have said according to their paper. I am new to this and not sure if this is exactly what they mean. Could you please help me out

Comment: Your mistake is either to replace 64 with 1 or to add a layer of dense.

Comment: @giser_yugang thats whta I thought but the architecture of the model in the paper mentions only these two dense layers

Comment: The paper may use one-hot, which changed from one-dimensional to 64 dimensional. Maybe you should read the paper carefully.